# opening of eclipse files written to java

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to open a file in eclipse but I get this error[image: error is this:The Class File Viewer cannot handle the given input ('org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput').]

my friends i want to open the eclipse file that i write from befroe on other pc but it does not open and tell me this error;

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please check the FAQ [ask] on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. Your question is missing some information to get a good answer, such as what is your actual problem, and what did you try to achieve.

Comment: What is an eclipse file? It looks like you're just trying to open a file without ".java" extension in eclipse...?

Comment: If you are trying to open ".class" file. You cannot, directly. You have to decompile the same and then try opening it. Make sure it's in you Java Build Path.

Comment: @AtulDwivedi You can open .class files but the class file editor you get is not very useful.

Comment: How are you trying to open this file? Are you opening something that is not in the workspace?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to open a .class file which is not in the current workspace. The class file editor does not support this and gives this error when you do this.

Note: The class file editor does not attempt to convert the contents to Java, it just shows you the Java bytecode.

Comment: Fine, but you still cannot open a file which is not in the workspace with the .class file editor.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the file is visible in eclipse but it is impossible for you to open it. Try to Project -> clean workspace.

Comment: The fact that it is using `FileStoreEditorInput` means the file is not in the workspace.

Comment: I have never faced the same issue, but it is possible to link an external file to the workspace, that might be the case?